# Flutter blur area in image using mask generated by IA

Tags: image, flutter, dart, blur

i'm having hard time to blur area in image using mask generated by IA output

i'm receiving 2d array from backend to blur specific area in the image

here is sample: https://ibb.co/w08dCyY

pink-dark area represent 0 in the 2d array

yellow area represent 1 in the 2d array

2d array represent the image mask to blur faces area

Canvas and Paint in flutter didn't helped me because " MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 10); " doesn't recieve sigmaX and sigmaY as argument so it doesn't really make the blur

how can i blur some areas in image in flutter ?

Comment: you need `ImageFilter.blur`, not `MaskFilter.blur`

Comment: to blur widget yes, but not designed to use it in Paint()

Comment: yes, it is designed to use with `Paint` - check `Paint` official documentation

Comment: so what exactly does not work with `ImageFilter.blur`?